# $_SESSION will not work

Tags: php

can anyone help me?  my session does not save. when i make other page and use session and then send it to a other page it's work. when i use wamp to test my server it works. can  anyone help me ? Its sends me back to the login page.

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){

    $username = bin2hex($_SESSION['id']);

}else{

    echo "<script> window.location.replace('Login.php') </script>";
}
```

on login page

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['id'] = $userunhex;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: So where are you runing this code when it does not work

Comment: i'm running it on the server and it wont work

Comment: _i'm running it on the server_ A bit more detail about ___the server___ would be useful

Comment: is a server on the site versio.nl. just a hosting package with php version  5.5.31

Comment: error_reporting(-1); when i do that i dont get a error and when i alert the session then i get a empty alert box

Comment: are you displaying them?

Comment: plus, you're using `bin2hex` and probably changing its signature. Also, we have no idea where this is assigned or used later on `$userunhex`.  RTM on that function http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php - you also need to check if the session is set in the login file also.

Comment: when i change that it still dont work

Comment: @nandodavis Have a look at what I've posted below. You will need to take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Its sends me back to the login page."*

That is because the session array is (*obviously*) empty and has not been assigned to anything.

Plus, you need to switch your session array and variable around in your second file, being the login page/file.

(Tested TRUE)

**File1.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();

$_SESSION['id'] = 123; // My own test assignment. You need to use the one you are using.

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){

// This is actually valid syntax.
//    echo $username= bin2hex($_SESSION['id']);

    $username = bin2hex($_SESSION['id']);

}else{


//  echo "Not set";

    echo "<script> window.location.replace('Login.php') </script>";
}
```

**File2.php** and checking if the session is set also.

Changing `$_SESSION['id'] = $userunhex;` to `$userunhex = $_SESSION['id'];`

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){

    $userunhex = $_SESSION['id'];

    echo $userunhex;

}

else {
    echo "Session is not set".
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all. i just fixed it

did this:

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['id'];
$username = bin2hex($username);
if(isset($username)){

}else{
  echo "<script> window.location.replace('Login.php') </script>";
}
```